How to estimate the amount to get from Raydium CPMM withdraw instruction
Is there a way I can estimate that amount that I will receive from calling the CPMM withdraw instruction
const { execute } = await raydium.cpmm.withdrawLiquidity({
    poolInfo,
    poolKeys,
    lpAmount,
    txVersion: TxVersion.V0,
    slippage,
});

